# Random COMException on Web App "The handle is invalid"

Tags: windows-xp, asp.net-3.5, iis-5, web-applications, comexception

All of a sudden, I am consistently getting a weird COMException on this machine when I try serve a web app with IIS.  I never used to have any problems with this.

Stack Trace:

```
[COMException (0x80070006): The handle is invalid. (0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))]

[FileLoadException]
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

How can I fix this?  I need this server to be working later today for a demo.

Things I have tried:

- Stop/Start in IIS
- aspnet_regiis -i
- reboot

Comment: I thought about putting this question on ServerFault, but I believe it is a problem with ASP.NET

Comment: Weirdest thing about this: I have no COM objects in this web app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not actually a COM error, it is a Windows error, wrapped in a COM error code.  It is a very low-level error, little can be distilled from the error code or the stack trace.  There are plenty of hits when you Google the message, [here's one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/8703945e-6c76-49a3-9999-7045b6645486) that looks good.  Be sure to find more yourself if that's not a good match.

Comment: Thanks!!  Impersonation was enabled on the Web Site in global configuration for ASP.NET, and disabling it fixed my problem.  Not sure how it got enabled in the first place.